# Mongo Connection Error in Azure Linux App Service using docker image

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, docker, azure-cosmosdb

I've deployed a docker image to an Azure Linux App Service which contains a node app. The app is failing to start properly because it can't connect to a Mongo version of Cosmo DB.

> error:  MongoError: failed to connect to server [***.documents.azure.com:10255] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN ***.documents.azure.com:10255]

I'm using mongoose and the following to connect:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, { useMongoClient: true });
```

Running the app in a container locally on my machine works. Is there something I'm missing? Some DNS/Firewall setting?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "node", "main.js" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to do with the image I was using:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest
```

There seems to be a problem with DNS when using this image when deploying it to Azure.

Switched to use

```
FROM node:latest
```

and everything is now working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, open outbound ports 10250-10256 and 443 to work with Cosmos DB. Also, make sure your mongodb connection string has ?ssl=true parameter set.

Comment: Is that a setting in the Dockerfile or something in the App Service in Azure?

Comment: That is a client-side setting - those ports are obviously open on Azure side and they don't change.